# Dificuldades com posicionamento de elementos css

Tags: html5, css3

Preciso arrumar o posicionamento desse menu
o *footer* esta totalmente fora de cor, a cor preta esta acima dele, o posicionamento de textos e imagens estão OK, porém o elementos CSS  e até mesmo o corpo esta fora de posição

```css
/* efeito dentro do corpo, definido fonte e tamanho da margin em 0. */

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Trebuchet MS;
  background: #f7f7f7;
}
/* denindo o header com tamanho 100 %, e a cor de fundo Azul, header fixo */

header {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #2c3e50;
}
/* cancelando o checkbox, pois o mesmo foi usado na função do icon, assim deixei invisivel ao usuario */

#btn-menu {
  display: none;
}
/* definindo o icon , com tamanho de altura, largura e espaçamento */

header label {
  display: none;
  width: 40px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 10px;
}
/* para quando passar o mouse */

header label:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.menu ul {
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
}
/*Definindo proporção de crescimento de cada elemento*/

.menu li {
  text-align: right;
}
/*efeito de mouse, quando passar o mouse muda de cor*/

.menu li:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.menu li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 96%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0px 2%;
}
#img-menu img {
  width: 100%;
}
#img-menu {
  max-height: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
/*Cor letras*/

p,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4 {
  /*color:#999;*/
}
/*selecionando barra2*/

#selling-points {
  margin-top: 60px;
}
#selling-points li {
  float: left;
  width: 23%;
  padding: 1%;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  line-height: 1.6 em;
}
#selling-points:after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  clear: both;
}
/*definindo cor do footer*/

/*
main{
    padding: 20px;
    }*/

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  /*Header estilo*/
  header label {
    display: block;
  }
  .menu {
    /*tamanho, cor e posição Barra Lateral*/
    position: absolute;
    background: #2c3e50;
    /*tamanho barra lateral*/
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: -70%;
    /*tempo de transição da barra*/
    transition: all 0.5s;
  }
  /*Definindo li central, ou seja, barra central como  barra lateral*/
  .menu ul {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  /*cor do traçado embaixo dos topicos que são links diretos*/
  .menu li {
    text-align: left;
    flex-grow: 1;
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
    font-family: Trebuchet MS;
  }
  #btn-menu:checked ~ .menu {
    margin: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <title>Header</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <input type="checkbox" id="btn-menu">
    <label for="btn-menu">
      <img src="icones/icon-menu.png" alt="" width="35" height="32">
    </label>
    <nav class="menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Inicio</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Agua</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">APS</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">UNIP</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <div id="img-menu">
    <img src="Imagem/Menu.png" alt="banner">
  </div>

  <main class="wrapper">

    <section id="selling-points">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <img src="icones/icon1.png" alt="selling-points" width="104" height="98">
          <h3>Titulo</h3>
          <p>Os três jogadores com mais de 23 anos que disputarão as Olimpíadas ainda são um mistério.</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="icones/icon2.png" alt="selling-points" width="104" height="98">
          <h3>Agua</h3>
          <p>Os três jogadores com mais de 23 anos que disputarão as Olimpíadas ainda são um mistério.</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="icones/icon3.png" alt="selling-points" width="104" height="98">
          <h3>Water</h3>
          <p>Os três jogadores com mais de 23 anos que disputarão as Olimpíadas ainda são um mistério.</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="icones/icon4.png" alt="selling-points" width="104" height="98">
          <h3>Cartola</h3>
          <p>Os três jogadores com mais de 23 anos que disputarão as Olimpíadas ainda são um mistério.</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </section>
  </main>

  <footer>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <ul>

        <li>
          <h4>Titulo Footer</h4>
        </li>
        <li>(11)98755-6589</li>
        <li>matheusilvaz@gmail.com</li>
        <li>Ferraz de Vasconcelos</li>
        <li>Infelizmente trabalhando de sabado</li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <h4>Titulo dois</h4>
        </li>
        <li>(11)98755-6589</li>
        <li>matheusilvaz@gmail.com</li>
        <li>Ferraz de Vasconcelos</li>
        <li>Infelizmente trabalhando de sabado</li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <h4>Titulo Tres</h4>
        </li>
        <li>(11)98755-6589</li>
        <li>matheusilvaz@gmail.com</li>
        <li>Ferraz de Vasconcelos</li>
        <li>Infelizmente trabalhando de sabado</li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <h4>Titulo Quatro</h4>
        </li>
        <li>(11)98755-6589</li>
        <li>matheusilvaz@gmail.com</li>
        <li>Ferraz de Vasconcelos</li>
        <li>Infelizmente trabalhando de sabado</li>
      </ul>
      <div id="copyright">&copy; 2016 GJVM; Todos os direitos reservados; Trabalho Unip.
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
```

Comment: Para uma ajuda real, você precisa mostrar um esboço/desenho de como deverá ser a tela final. Da fora como está feita a pergunta, faltam detalhes. Edite para melhorar a pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

amigo a unica ideia que posso te dar para te ajudar nesse momento e que faca o seguinte.. clique com o botao direito sobre sua pagina no local onde vc quer modificar .. abrira ao lado direito de sua tela uma janela com os codigos de sua pagina ... veja que conforme vc passar o mouse sobre as linhas de codigos ele te indicara aonde esta o conteudo daquele codigo inclusive ja mesma janela na parte de baixo aparecera o css utilizado...
ai amigo e so se divertir e ir alterando tudo ater vc achar o local exato onde a modificação ficara de acordo como vc quer.. é claro alterando apenas na janela não irar mudar na sua programação porem te indicara a linha aonde esta o cogido e aonde ele ta ....espero que tenha ajudado[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]